# VueJS-3 How to render <router-view></router-view> from vue-router?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-router4

In vuejs 2 I was able to render  directly in the router by return a render html tag. I'm trying to do the same things in vue3 with vue-router 4, but it doesn't appear to work:

```
{
        path: 'posts',
        redirect: '/posts/all',
        name: 'posts',
        meta: {'breadcrumb': 'Posts'},
        component: {
            render() {
                return h('router-view');
            }
        },
        children: [ //Lots of sub routes here that I could load off the anonymous router-view]
}
```

Any idea how I can get the component to render that router-view and allow me to use my children routes? I rather not load up a single component just to house "". This worked perfectly in vue-router 3, no idea what is wrong with 4. I also am importing the {h} from 'vue'.

Answer (score 8):

From the Vue 3 Render Function [docs](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/render-function-api.html#_3-x-syntax-4):

> In 3.x, with VNodes being context-free, we can no longer use a string ID to implicitly lookup registered components. Instead, we need to use an imported [`resolveComponent`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/global-api.html#resolvecomponent) method:

You can still do `h('div')` because it's not a component, but for components you have to use [`resolveComponent`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/global-api.html#resolvecomponent):

```js
import { h, resolveComponent } from Vue;  // import `resolveComponent` too

component: {
  render() {
    return h(resolveComponent('router-view'))
  }
},
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to use the [runtime compiler](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html#explanation-of-different-builds), you could use the `template` option *(not recommended because the compiler increases app size)*:

```html
component: {
  template: `<router-view></router-view>`
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since Vue Router 4, you can use the `RouterView` component directly:

```js
import { RouterView } from 'vue-router';

//...

{
    path: 'posts',
    redirect: '/posts/all',
    name: 'posts',
    meta: {'breadcrumb': 'Posts'},
    component: RouterView, // <- here
    children: [ /* ... */ ]
}
```

Source: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2105#issuecomment-761854147

P.S. As per linked issue, there are allegedly some problems with `<transition>` when you use this technique, so use caution.